# How do I deploy ASP.NET 5 / .NET Core in Linux / Mac?

Tags: asp.net, .net, mod-mono, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

With the recent release of [ASP .NET 5 features](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5) it is quite evident that MS is now targeting more on cross-platform .NET App development (also increasing its bond with Mono).

I would like to know the best practices to deploy an ASP .NET 5 code in Linux / MAC - Considering the fact that I will be using a non-IIS server. Should I use [MOD_MONO](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/) or [Kestrel](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Servers#microsoftaspnetserverkestrel-kestrel)?

Will this setup be Production ready ? I understand it is too early to decide, but does anyone have any hands-on experience ?

Answer (score 2):

For now you should use Mono and Kestrel. ASP.NET 5 + CoreCLR is not yet available for *nix.

ASP.NET 5 is still in the pre-release stage and that's how you should treat the *nix story too.

Comment: You can use mono or coreclr with kestrel

Comment: If I choose coreclr with kestrel, is there a nice packaging" way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by nice packaging way? The packaging is the same as with any other server: `dnu publish`

Comment: Is this still relevant?